More professional way to write the code
I have this code(shorter version), there are 22 more schemes not just 3. This one works fine. I am trying to simply this code and write a nice and better version of it. Because I have more than 25 schemes it becomes very ugly and very difficult to read. If possible make it more efficient. I am sure there must be a much much better way to achieve the same result.
(*Functions and guess for Example 1*)

f[1][x_] := x^4 + 2 x^3 - 14 x^2 + 2 x + 1;
g[1][x_] := Power[-2 x^3 + 14 x^2 - 2 x - 1, (4)^-1];
p[1][0] = 28/10;
(*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*)
(*Functions and guess for Example 2*)

f[2][x_] := 2 x - Log[10, x] - 7;
g[2][x_] := 1/2 (Log[10, x] + 7);
p[2][0] = 6/10;
(*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*)
(*Functions and guess for Example 3*)

f[3][x_] := Tan[x] - x;
g[3][x_] := Pi + ArcTan[x];
p[3][0] = 4;
(*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*)
(*Functions and guess for Example 4*)

f[4][x_] := x/(1 - x) - 5*Log[(4/10 (1 - x))/(4/10 - 5/10*x)] + 445977/100000;
g[4][x_] := 1 - 1/10/(5/10 - 4/10*Exp[-(1/5) (x/(1 - x) + 445977/100000)]);
p[4][0] = 7/10;
(*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*)
(*Functions and guess for Example 5*)

f[5][x_] := -(1674/1000) + 2511/1000*x + 147445/10000*x^2 - 779075/100000*x^3 + x^4;
g[5][x_] := Sqrt[10000/147445 (1674/1000 - 2511/1000*x + 779075/100000*x^3 - x^4)];
p[5][0] = 1/10;
(*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*)


k = 1/(n + 1); 
w = 1/10;
b = d = 3/5;
c = 1/5; 
pre = 200; 
e = 4;
l = 3/4;
(*Parameters and precision for all Examples ends here*)


Do[
mann[j][0] = p[j][0];
mann[j][n + 1] = SetAccuracy[(1 - k) mann[j][n] + (k) g[j][mann[j][n]], pre];


ish[j][0] = p[j][0];
ishr[j][n] = SetAccuracy[(1 - k) ish[j][n] + (k) g[j][ish[j][n]], pre];
ish[j][n + 1] = SetAccuracy[(1 - k) ish[j][n] + (k) g[j][ishr[j][n]], pre];

noor[j][0] = p[j][0];
noorr[j][n] = SetAccuracy[(1 - k) noor[j][n] + (k) g[j][noor[j][n]], pre];
noorq[j][n] = SetAccuracy[(1 - k) noor[j][n] + (k) g[j][noorr[j][n]], pre];
noor[j][n + 1] = SetAccuracy[(1 - k) noor[j][n] + (k) g[j][noorq[j][n]], pre];, {j, 1, 5}, {n, 0, e}
];


Do[
  Print[TableForm[{{ScientificForm[Abs[mann[k][e + 1] - mann[k][e]], 2], 
  ScientificForm[Abs[ish[k][e + 1] - ish[k][e]], 2], 
  ScientificForm[Abs[noor[k][e + 1] - noor[k][e]],2]}, 
  {ScientificForm[Abs[f[k][mann[k][e]]], 2], 
  ScientificForm[Abs[f[k][ish[k][e]]], 2], 
  ScientificForm[Abs[f[k][noor[k][e + 1]]], 2]}}, 
  TableHeadings -> {{"Itr Error Ex"[k], "Residual Error Ex"[k]}, {"Mann Ex"[k], "IS Ex"[k], "Noor Ex"[k]}}]], {k, 1, 5}
  ]


Are you sure that pre = $MachinePrecision; does not suffice here. That might speed up things a lot. (But the example si just too tiny to time it properly.)

The examples and pre here are not actual ones. I just want a better way to write this program.

Let me say that your users will probably find it annoying that you print the results instead of returning a data structure that contains the result and that is easy to manipulate afterwards. The Mathematica frontend handles Print really slowly. Print clutters the notebook without asking. In contrast, the return value can be hidden simply by appending a semicolon.
Also, I would recommend to use vectors of pure functions instead of using downvalues for the symbols f and g . And I think p, mann, ish, noor etc. could all be simple matrices. Downvalue lookups already require quite sophisticated data structures. Overall, "professionalism" would be to always use the simplest data structure that meets the requirements (the current requirements or the requirements in a foreseeable future).
There are several reasons to use simple data structures:

Performance: fancy do-it-all data structures are typically larger and slower. As an example: I have seen a couple of projects by now in which people used data structures based on linked lists (or pointer-based trees), although the size of the final data structure could have been determined ahead and although no or only few surgical operatations had to be made after the construction. Using simple 1- or 2-dimensional arrays instead was almost always the key for making the code faster.

Move semantics: Using down values to store data is also problematic, because it makes it difficult to move around data. If simple lists or matrices would not work, then I would recommend using nested Associations with expressive key names. They encapsulate the data quite nicely and lazy copying is implemented for them.

Arithmetic: On matrices you can do things like adding one row into another, or mapping a function over a row. This can save you a Do-loop, which makes the code easier to read and faster.

Principle of least surprise: Fellow developers (and yourself) do not have to wonder why you picked the fancy data structure and what side effects and constraints this would imply.
Maybe this is a bit biased towards my own habits, but I would say that people expect symbols with downvalues to be used primarily for implementing functions (with pattern matching and maybe some evaluations for special values being stored). And that people would expect that data would be stored in container data types like nested Lists or nested Associations. Admittedly, Mathematica and programming techniques like memoization make it easy to blur this distinction.


Edit
Having understood the code a bit better, it occured to me that only the values of mann, ish, noor in the last column are actually needed at the end of the computation. Then it is of course better to not use matrices, but just vectors for these quantities. During the calculations, only one of these values is need at a time, so one can make the Do-loops less memory bound by doing the following:
ClearAll[flist, glist, p, mann, ish, noor];

flist = {
   x |-> x^4 + 2 x^3 - 14 x^2 + 2 x + 1,
   x |-> 2 x - Log[10, x] - 7,
   x |-> Tan[x] - x,
   x |-> x/(1 - x) - 5 Log[(4/10 (1 - x))/(4/10 - 5/10*x)] + 445977/100000,
   x |-> -(1674/1000) + 2511/1000 x + 147445/10000 x^2 - 779075/100000 x^3 + x^4
   };
glist = {
   x |-> Power[-2 x^3 + 14 x^2 - 2 x - 1, 1/4],
   x |-> 1/2 (Log[10, x] + 7),
   x |-> Pi + ArcTan[x],
   x |-> 1 - 1/10/(5/10 - 4/10 Exp[-(1/5) (x/(1 - x) + 445977/100000)]),
   x |-> Sqrt[10000/147445 (1674/1000 - 2511/1000 x + 779075/100000 x^3 - x^4)]
   };

p = {28/10, 6/10, 4, 7/10, 1/10};

mann = ish = noor = SetAccuracy[p, pre];

Do[
  Block[{g, mannj, ishj, noorj, a, b},
    
    g = glist[[j]];
    
    (*Read initial values.*)
    mannj = mann[[j]];
    ishj = ish[[j]];
    noorj = noor[[j]];
    
    Do[
     mannj = (1 - k) mannj + k g[mannj];
     
     a = (1 - k) ishj;
     b = a + k g[ishj];
     ishj = a + k g[b];
     
     a = (1 - k) noorj;
     b = a + k g[noorj];
     b = a + k g[b];
     noorj = a + k g[b];
     , {n, 1, e + 1}];
    
    (*Write final values.*)
    mann[[j]] = mannj;
    ish[[j]] = ishj;
    noor[[j]] = noorj;
    ];
  
  , {j, 1, 5}];

In the end, mann[[j]], ish[[j]], noor[[j]] from this implementation should equal mann[j][e+1], ish[j][e+1], noor[j][e+1] from OP's implementation,
Edit 2
Since OP mentioned that they would have to implement various "schemes" and assuming that the schemes are what is to be done to mann, ish, noor, I would recommend to do the following:
schemes = Association[];

schemes["mann"] = {init, g} |-> Module[{result, x},
    x = init;
    Do[x = (1 - k) x + k g[x], {n, 1, e + 1}];
    x
    ];

schemes["ish"] = {init, g} |-> Module[{result, x, a, b},
    x = init;
    Do[
     a = (1 - k) x;
     b = a + k g[x];
     x = a + k g[b];
     , {n, 1, e + 1}];
    x
    ];

schemes["noor"] = {init, g} |-> Module[{result, x, a, b},
    x = init;
    Do[
     a = (1 - k) x;
     b = a + k g[x];
     b = a + k g[b];
     x = a + k g[b];
     , {n, 1, e + 1}];
    x
    ];

init = SetAccuracy[p, pre];
results = Map[scheme |-> MapThread[scheme, {init, glist}], schemes];

Then result is an Association whose keys are the names of the schemes (as a String) and whose values are the resulting vectors.
Edit 3
OP answered on this post in a comment:

Thank you for your detailed answer..however this does not work.

Comments like these make me personally very, very angry and make me question my engagement on this site. This is a very lazy way to report a bug. It gives almost no useful information to the person who invested a considerable portion of their time into solving another person's problem. And at the same time it passively aggressively demands a quick fix for the bug.
This leads me to put the following recommendation for professionality onto the list:

Give concise but complete bug reports. What exactly did you do? What exactly did happen? In which way did this differ from what you expected? Have any errors been thrown? What did the error messages say? Did the computed result differ from the correct result? Or did the implementation fail to meet some hidden constraint of your project?

After running OP's code and my code again, I finally found out that the code executed without error message but that the results differ. After some guessing around, I looked into the definitions of "constants" and found the following line:
k = 1/(n + 1); 

The letter n showed up in blue, which means it was undefined. Note that n is the loop variable in some Do loop. Speaking of the principle of least surprise: Nobody will expect that your loop variable shows up in the definition of k.
So, what went wrong? During the development of the above code I had set n = 1 to test the loop body for the first iteration. So, k always evaluated to 2 in OP's code as well as in mine. The results always coincided. Hence, an external definition of the symbol for loop variable changed the working of the whole code. This is extremely dangerous and can lead to day-long debugging sessions. This brings me to the next recommendations:

Scope all temporary symbols. Put them always into the smallest scope possible.

Make dependence on non-constant quantities visible by using function calls or make them fully explicit. Hiding dependencies on a loop variable is evil. This is particularly important when you start to refactor your code to make it more performant.


Finally, here is the fix for the code in Edit 1:
mann = ish = noor = SetAccuracy[p, pre];

Do[
  Block[{g, mannj, ishj, noorj, a, b, k},
    g = glist[[j]];
    (*Read initial values.*)
    mannj = mann[[j]];
    ishj = ish[[j]];
    noorj = noor[[j]];
    Do[
     k = 1/n;

     mannj = (1 - k) mannj + k g[mannj];

     a = (1 - k) ishj;
     b = a + k g[ishj];
     ishj = a + k g[b];

     a = (1 - k) noorj;
     b = a + k g[noorj];
     b = a + k g[b];
     noorj = a + k g[b];, {n, 1, e + 1}];
    
    (*Write final values.*)
    
    mann[[j]] = mannj;
    ish[[j]] = ishj;
    noor[[j]] = noorj;];
  , {j, 1, 5}];

And the fix for the code in Edit 2:
schemes = Association[];

schemes["mann"] = {init, g} |-> Module[{result, x, k},
    x = init;
    Do[
     k = 1/(n + 1);
     x = (1 - k) x + k g[x]
     , {n, 0, e}];
    x
    ];

schemes["ish"] = {init, g} |-> Module[{result, x, a, b, k},
    x = init;
    Do[
     k = 1/(n + 1);
     a = (1 - k) x;
     b = a + k g[x];
     x = a + k g[b];
     , {n, 0, e}];
    x];

schemes["noor"] = {init, g} |-> Module[{result, x, a, b, k},
    x = init;
    Do[
     k = 1/(n + 1);
     a = (1 - k) x;
     b = a + k g[x];
     b = a + k g[b];
     x = a + k g[b];
     , {n, 0, e}];
    x];


Thank you for your detailed answer..however this does not work.
